# need on creating list of discretionary in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a list of dictionaries using the following python code, but I get a duplicate copy in list only

my code is :

```
def jsonHandler():
    mqttDataToPublish = {}
    jsonreaddata = []
    jsoncommadnData = {}
   
    for i in range(0,2,1):
        for j in range(0,3,1):
            print()
            print()
            print("befor request jsonreaddata",jsonreaddata)
            print("first URL is ", j+1)
            jsoncommadnData['command'] = j+1
            jsoncommadnData['data'] = j+2
            print("command and it url",jsoncommadnData)
            print()
            print()
            print("after request jsonreaddata",jsonreaddata)
            jsonreaddata.append(jsoncommadnData)
            print()
            print()
            print("after append jsonreaddata",jsonreaddata)
def main():
    jsonHandler()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

expected output is
jsonreaddata = {[{'command': 1, 'data': 2}, {'command': 2, 'data': 3}, {'command': 3, 'data': 4}......

But got the following: all duplicate
after append jsonreaddata [{'command': 3, 'data': 4}, {'command': 3, 'data': 4}, {'command': 3, 'data': 4}, {'command': 3, 'data': 4}, {'command': 3, 'data': 4}, {'command': 3, 'data': 4}]

logs are:

python3 test.py

befor request jsonreaddata []
first URL is  1
command and it url {'command': 1, 'data': 2}

after request jsonreaddata []

after append jsonreaddata [{'command': 1, 'data': 2}]

befor request jsonreaddata [{'command': 1, 'data': 2}]
first URL is  2
command and it url {'command': 2, 'data': 3}

after request jsonreaddata [{'command': 2, 'data': 3}]

after append jsonreaddata [{'command': 2, 'data': 3}, {'command': 2, 'data': 3}]

befor request jsonreaddata [{'command': 2, 'data': 3}, {'command': 2, 'data': 3}]
first URL is  3
command and it url {'command': 3, 'data': 4}

after request jsonreaddata [{'command': 3, 'data': 4}, {'command': 3, 'data': 4}]

after append jsonreaddata [{'command': 3, 'data': 4}, {'command': 3, 'data': 4}, {'command': 3, 'data': 4}]

befor request jsonreaddata [{'command': 3, 'data': 4}, {'command': 3, 'data': 4}, {'command': 3, 'data': 4}]
first URL is  1
command and it url {'command': 1, 'data': 2}

after request jsonreaddata [{'command': 1, 'data': 2}, {'command': 1, 'data': 2}, {'command': 1, 'data': 2}]

after append jsonreaddata [{'command': 1, 'data': 2}, {'command': 1, 'data': 2}, {'command': 1, 'data': 2}, {'command': 1, 'data': 2}]

befor request jsonreaddata [{'command': 1, 'data': 2}, {'command': 1, 'data': 2}, {'command': 1, 'data': 2}, {'command': 1, 'data': 2}]
first URL is  2
command and it url {'command': 2, 'data': 3}

after request jsonreaddata [{'command': 2, 'data': 3}, {'command': 2, 'data': 3}, {'command': 2, 'data': 3}, {'command': 2, 'data': 3}]

after append jsonreaddata [{'command': 2, 'data': 3}, {'command': 2, 'data': 3}, {'command': 2, 'data': 3}, {'command': 2, 'data': 3}, {'command': 2, 'data': 3}]

befor request jsonreaddata [{'command': 2, 'data': 3}, {'command': 2, 'data': 3}, {'command': 2, 'data': 3}, {'command': 2, 'data': 3}, {'command': 2, 'data': 3}]
first URL is  3
command and it url {'command': 3, 'data': 4}

after request jsonreaddata [{'command': 3, 'data': 4}, {'command': 3, 'data': 4}, {'command': 3, 'data': 4}, {'command': 3, 'data': 4}, {'command': 3, 'data': 4}]

after append jsonreaddata [{'command': 3, 'data': 4}, {'command': 3, 'data': 4}, {'command': 3, 'data': 4}, {'command': 3, 'data': 4}, {'command': 3, 'data': 4}, {'command': 3, 'data': 4}]

can help what is missing or wrong in my code

Comment: Of course, because you keep appending the *same dictionary to the list over and over*: `jsonreaddata.append(jsoncommadnData)`.

Comment: after clearing the jsoncommadndata in inner loop I am able to achieve what I want .